# How to use a variable and try in a function

Tags: python

I need to use try to check if a variable is between 1 and 3 and is a number.  This was working but I changed my program into functions and now I am getting errors about variables being referenced before assignment.

I've tried using select_level() function and level variable in a try but it doesn't work.

```
def select_level():
    print("Welcome to the math quiz.  To get started you will need to select a level.")
    while True:
        try:
            return int(input("Press 1 for Addition, 2 for Subtraction, 3 for Multiplication, and then press the 'Enter' key. "))
            if 1 <= select_level <= 3:
                    break
            else:
                print("Please enter a valid number.")
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a valid number.")

level = select_level()
```

I want the program to say please enter a valid number if the number entered is not 1, 2 or 3.  Instead, if I type any other number (for example 0) then the program doesn't work.  I works for strings but not for random numbers.

Edit:
Here's my full code

```
import random

rounds = 0

def select_level():
    print("Welcome to the math quiz.  To get started you will need to select a level.")
    while True:
        try:
            return int(input("Press 1 for Addition, 2 for Subtraction, 3 for Multiplication, and then press the 'Enter' key. "))
            if 1 <= level <= 3:
                    break
            else:
                print("Please enter a valid number.")
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a valid number.")

def generate():
    ''' Returns the numbers as a tuple '''
    number_one = random.randrange(1,10)
    number_two = random.randrange(1,10)
    return (number_one, number_two)

def solve(level, num_12):
    rounds = 0
    number_one, number_two = num_12
    while rounds < 10:
        if level == 1:
            solution = number_one + number_two
            print("What is ", number_one, " plus ", number_two, "?", sep="")
            user_ans = input()
        elif level == 2:
            solution = number_one - number_two
            print("What is ", number_one, " minus ", number_two, "?", sep="")
            user_ans = input()
        elif level == 3:
            solution = number_one * number_two
            print("What is ", number_one, " times by ", number_two, "?", sep="")
            user_ans = input()
        else:
            print("Please enter a valid number.")

        if user_ans == "x":
            rounds = 10
        else:
            try:
                ans_int = int(user_ans)
                if ans_int == solution:
                    print("Correct")
                    number_one = random.randrange(1,10)
                    number_two = random.randrange(1,10)
                    rounds = rounds + 1
                else:
                    print("Try again")
            except ValueError:
                print("Please enter a valid number.")

    print("Thanks for playing")

def main():
    # first get your level and set it to the function, this will make the "return" be set as level
    level = select_level()
    # do the same for num_12
    num_12 = generate()
    # start your solve but send level and num_12 as inputs to be used in the function
    solve(level, num_12)

main()
```

And my error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ben.jones/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2019.10.41019/pythonFiles/ptvsd_launcher.py", line 43, in <module>
    main(ptvsdArgs)
  File "/Users/ben.jones/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2019.10.41019/pythonFiles/lib/python/old_ptvsd/ptvsd/__main__.py", line 432, in main
    run()
  File "/Users/ben.jones/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2019.10.41019/pythonFiles/lib/python/old_ptvsd/ptvsd/__main__.py", line 316, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target, run_name='__main__')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/Volumes/BEN JONES/Assessment/adjusted.py", line 67, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Volumes/BEN JONES/Assessment/adjusted.py", line 65, in main
    solve(level, num_12)
  File "/Volumes/BEN JONES/Assessment/adjusted.py", line 42, in solve
    if user_ans == "x":
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'user_ans' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: "and now I am getting errors about variables being referenced before assignment." Always post the full error message. In any case, this is a common error, have you done *any* research on it? There are probably 1000 duplicates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning directly the value of the input before you are doing the validation check. Also you are validating an variable which is not assignment. Try this:

```
def select_level():
    print("Welcome to the math quiz.  To get started you will need to select a level.")
    while True:
        try:
            selected_level = int(input("Press 1 for Addition, 2 for Subtraction, 3 for Multiplication, and then press the 'Enter' key. "))
            if 1 <= selected_level <= 3:
                return selected_level
            else:
                print("Please enter a valid number.")
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a valid number.")

level = select_level()
```

**Additional to your edit:**
In your function `def solve(level, num_12):` not all if else cases assigning the variable `user_ans`. Add `user_ans = None` before the if statement than it should also fix this problem, or add `continue` in the `else` block where `user_ans` is not assigned.